# Xcode 9 compiled app and iOS 9.5.3 (iPad 2)

Tags: ios, xcode9

Anyone noticed issues with apps that are created with Xcode 9 and do not seem to work on iOS 9.5.3 and in this case an older iPad 2?

I have a customer that downloaded my app that I’ve complied and uploaded with Xcode 9, but when he installs the app it crashes straight away, and on some occasions in a flash of 2 sec. will display the interface builder screen layout of the app (ie all the views, buttons etc that are visible on interface builder but with a normal app nicely hidden until needed etc).

The minimum development target in Xcode is set to 8.2 so I assume it will and should be backwards compatible?

Comment: Did you try the iOS 9 simulator?

Comment: Yes, no issues with Xcode 9 simulator with ios 9

Comment: I have included the person on Test Flight, and he tried running the old version build with xcode 8. That seems to work fine. If I then let him try a version compiled with Xcode 9, the above mentioned issues appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the device is jailbroken.. My latest app version includes a check for a jailbroken device, and does not allow the app to load when it detects one. 
I Could reproduce the exact behaviour when triggering this validation check.